# apache camel polling a rest endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I have a rest endpoint sample.org which returns a json response of the form

```
{
  "response" : "pending" 
}
```

My route looks like this

```
from("http://sample.org")
.marshal(xmlFormatConverterUtil.getxmlJsonDataFormat())  //To convert into json as I receive data in xml format which needs to be converted to json
```

I read about [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) but couldn't find an example on how to keep polling the endpoint, till it returns response as "success".

Should a polling consumer be used ? If so can an example relevant to my case be illustrated. Any other resource to poll rest endpoints will be highly useful.

Comment: What do you mean poll the http endpoint? The route is listening to the exposed http url. Whenever someone sends a request to that url you will receive the message. There is no polling here.

Comment: By poll I mean, I will keep firing a GET request to the endpoint and each time I will check what my response is. When the response is success , I will stop polling the endpoint

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to start from a timer instead and then call the rest endpoint. Then you can check the result and if its  then stop the route using controlbus. The filter can be used to check if its pending and then just stop continue routing, and then the next timer will try again.

Someting along this pseudo route

```
from timer
  to http
  marshal
  filter (if pending)
     stop 
  end
  to something with positive response
  to controlbus stop route
```

You can find more details at

- http://camel.apache.org/timer
- http://camel.apache.org/controlbus
- http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html
- http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html

Comment: How is the new book coming along? My copy of 1st Edition is all dog eared.

Comment: We have 2.5 chapter to write, and Henryk will do the IoC chapter. But start of next year we have all that done, and then its proof, typesetting. So done before summer 2017.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and ended up [writing a custom endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html) for polling.

It works as a producer and polls the specified uri until a specified predicate has been met or polling reaches the maximum number of tries.

```java
from("direct:start")
  .to("poll:http://example.com/status?maxRetries=3&successPredicate=#statusSuccess")
```

The polling endpoint uses a simple processor that uses a polling consumer for polling.

```java
public class PollProcessor implements Processor {

    private final String uri;
    private final long requestTimeoutMs;
    private final long period;
    private final int maxTries;
    private final Predicate<Exchange> successPredicate;

    public PollProcessor(String uri, long requestTimeoutMs, long period, int maxTries, Predicate<Exchange> successPredicate) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(maxTries > 0);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(period >= 0);
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(successPredicate);

        this.uri = uri;
        this.requestTimeoutMs = requestTimeoutMs;
        this.period = period;
        this.maxTries = maxTries;
        this.successPredicate = successPredicate;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        PollingConsumer consumer = exchange.getContext().getEndpoint(uri).createPollingConsumer();

        for (int tryNumber = 1; tryNumber <= maxTries; ++tryNumber) {
            Exchange pollExchange = consumer.receive(requestTimeoutMs);
            if (successPredicate.test(pollExchange)) {
                exchange.setOut(pollExchange.getOut());
                exchange.setException(pollExchange.getException());
                return;
            }

            log.warn("Polling {} failed try number {}, waiting {} ms for next try...", uri, tryNumber);
            Thread.sleep(period);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Polling failed maximum allowed number of tries [" + maxTries + "], see log for details.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice :D I solved it by looping within my route with timer and retry count similar to what you did.